# grep to ignore special characters in a file

Tags: grep

I have a java file and I want to list the number of times the word `port` occurs. But the only problem is I have many functions which have the work port in it too.

Here is an example of a function :

```
public void portNum(){
  System.out.println("Your port number is ports port");
  port();
  //Reading your Port number
  readPortNumber();
}
```

I want to get only those lines which have `port` or port within `""` .

The output would be :

```
System.out.println("Your port number is ports port");
//Reading your Port number
```

So far I have

```
grep -i 'port'
```

Comment: What are you looking for?  Of the lines containing `port` (i.e., the output from `grep -i port`), which ones do you want and which ones do you not want?

Comment: How about grepping for `'port '` ( port space ) ? That should remove the functions, although may not be fool proof for all scenarios.

Comment: I want  those lines which are not functions with the word port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the lines that do not contain function declaration (as you have said in the comment):

```
$ grep -iwP 'port(?!\(.*\))' file.txt
  System.out.println("Your port number is ports port");
  //Reading your port number
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
netikras $ echo "$a"

sdff sd dfgdfg
"sjdkgv ojes port" asdsd


netikras $ echo "$a" |egrep -c "\".*port.*\""
1

netikras $ echo "$a" |egrep -c "\".*port.*\"|'.*port.*'"
1
```